# Prove that $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = (|x_2-x_1|)(\frac{|y_2-y_1|}{2}+1)+|y_2-y_1|$ is not a metric on $R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = (|x_2-x_1|)(\frac{|y_2-y_1|}{2}+1)+|y_2-y_1|$ is not a metric on $\mathbb R^2$.

My attempt was to find 3 points that violate the triangle inequality. However, I wasn't able to achieve that. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

$d((0,0),(0,1))=1$ and $d((0,1),(1,1))=1$ and $d((0,0),(1,1))=\frac{5}{2}$.